# Disable directory autocorrection in firefox

Tags: linux, firefox

I was attempting to look for directory traversal vulnerabilities/local file includes manually via my browser, but I noticed that firefox is apparently autocorrecting `../` into meaning literally the parent directory.

For example, if you have a URL like `http://www.example.com/a/asd/` , and you try to add `../` to the end of the URL, it will immediately take you to `http://www.example.com/a/`, instead of sending the GET request that I want to send.

Anyone know a way to disable this feature? I can work around it using other methods but I don't want my browser autocorrecting my GET requests.

Comment: `../` will always point to the previous directory. This is expected system-wide and I am pretty sure that this behavior cannot be changed.

Comment: A web browser is not a good tool for testing path traversal attacks. Typically you use a separate tool that allows to hand-craft HTTP requests. If you still want to use Firefox try one of the extensions which calm to allow custom HTTP requests like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-request-maker/

Comment: This was not the behavior in previous version of Firefox. And I like my super 1337 hacking tool known as a web browser.